# How to create a data-set for deep learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras

I want to train a CNN with Keras. I understand that `x_train` contains the data features and `y_train`the labels.

I tried `test_train_split(x_train,test_size=0.2,train_size=0.8)`.

How do I create `y_train`?

Comment: Which library are you getting the "test_train_split" function from? You should be able to pass both through. test_train_split(x_train, y_train) and then assign the result to four variables. x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
```

If it is Timeseries shuffle=False. test_size is 40% of your data. So you are going to train 60%

Comment: I mean how to preprocess x_train and y_train on 10 authors data?